# Citing in Latex

Tags: citing, natbib

I would like to cite something in a very specific form. For example, I want in my text to have exactly this

**....for further details see Diamond(1965, Appendix B)**

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass[preprint, 12pt, authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document} 

for further details see \cite[Appendix B]{Diamond1965}


\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

In my document i get this style (Diamond, 1965, Appendix B) which I do not like. Is something that I should handle through any options or change the bibstyle ?

Many thanks

Comment: Try using `\citet` instead of `\cite`?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem, here, is that `\cite` is no longer really supported by `natbib`. According to the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/natbib/natbib.pdf) (pp. 7-8):

> In the original versions of `natbib`, the traditional `\cite` command was used for both textual and parenthetical citations. The presence of an empty optional text in square brackets signalled parenthetical. This syntax has been retained for compatibility, but is no longer encouraged. This means that `\cite` (without notes) is the same as `\citet` in author–year mode, whereas in numerical mode, it is the same as `\citep`. The starred version, as well as the one or two optional notes, may also be used.

The `\citet` command (and its relatives) is what is supposed to be used for textual (in-line) citations, and the `\citep` command (and its relatives) is supposed to be used for parenthetical citations.

So, in your case, you want to use `\citet`, not `\cite`.

Here is a handy [`natbib` reference sheet](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php).