# \cite cites the name of the authors twice?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I have a bibtex file with

```
@Article{perignon2008banks,
Title                    = {Do banks overstate their Value-at-Risk?},
Author                   = {P{\'e}rignon, Christophe and Deng, Zi Yin and Wang, Zhi Jun},
Journal                  = {Journal of Banking \& Finance},
Year                     = {2008},
Number                   = {5},
Pages                    = {783--794},
Volume                   = {32},

Publisher                = {Elsevier}
}
```

in my tex file I have

```
\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

when using

```
\cite{perignon2008banks}
```

I get

[Pérignon et al.(2008)Pérignon,Deng and Wang]

What do I need to do in order to only cite [Pérignon et al.(2008)]?

Comment: Are you using the `natbib` package? `\cite` is a deprecated command. Try `\citet` or `\citep`, depending on what you want. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168079/32888).

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I forgot to type \usepackage{Natbib} thinking it was already being used

I corrected it and now its running smoothly like I wanted. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it's working! Is it okay if I vote to close this question?  Part of the goal of TeX.SX is to create a repository of knowledge, more so than being just a mere Q&A forum. And, as it stands, your question is pretty "localized" (*e.g.*, forgetting to load a package) and probably won't be all that helpful to future visitors of the site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved in comments